# How can I check if a node is a parent in jstree after I've clicked a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview, jstree

I'm creating a button to delete nodes after I selected them. I want to make it able to only delete child nodes. In order to do it, I need to check if the node is a parent or not.

So code would look something like

```
$(".delete-node").click(function() {
    // gets the selected nodes
    $('#jstree1').jstree(true).get_selected(); 

    if (data.instance.is_leaf) { 
        //My problem is HERE. Only delete if all nodes are children/not parent
        //here I delete the nodes selected
        $('#jstree1').jstree(true)
                     .delete_node($('#jstree1')
                     .jstree(true)
                     .get_selected()); 
    }
});
```

I know this is simple but I can't seem to put it to work. I'm kinda new to jQuery and JavaScript so what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to get the node by the id and then check if it is a parent. See code like below. Check demo -  [Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/ermakovnikolay/pen/vZyogo)

```
$('#jstree1')
  .jstree({
    core: {
      data: treeData,
      check_callback: true  // don't forget to set this param to true
    }
  });

$(".delete-node").click(function() {
  var tree = $('#jstree1').jstree();
  // gets the selected nodes
  var selectedNodeIds = tree.get_selected();
  selectedNodeIds.forEach(function(nodeId) {
    var node = tree.get_node(nodeId);
    if (!tree.is_parent(node)) {
      tree.delete_node(node)
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `$(element).children().length === 0` meaning it has no child nodes.

To delete all the child nodes in such case `$(element).children().remove()` will remove all the child nodes.

Comment: Just tried it but I'm still missing something. My code is looking like: if ($('.jstree-clicked').children().length === 0) {
               
               alert('haha');
           }

Comment: can you please highlight the condition that you feel is missing? i can help from there

Comment: The alert is not popping up meaning that the condition is not true. But why not? I mean, I select the nodes, I click the button, if nodes that are clicked - .jstree-clicked - has no children, It should give an alert but nothing happens.

Comment: can you output $('.jstree-clicked').length before doing this? maybe the selector path is not right. can you verify using the code mentioned?

Comment: I did as you said. On the  alert($('.jstree-clicked').children().length); i've been told that there are 2 childrens. So I guess my selector is wrong. I'm gonna think more about it, I think you provided me the path, I just need to follow it.

Comment: So, I realized I won't be able to use css selectors. So I need to use the jstree method to check if is a parent or not. Can you take a look on it? [https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=is_parent(obj)]